# CoreData leaks with fetched results arrays

Tags: arrays, ios, core-data, memory-leaks

I'm using CoreData to store objects like cars, trips, data recorded from GPS, etc.
When I fetch what I want to show a list of trips, some stats for a trip, or add a new car in my settings view controller, I use pretty much this kind of request:

```
- (void)getDataTrip
{
    // Fetched data trips.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DataTrip" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set predicate and sort orderings...
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idTrip = %@", self.idTrip];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Execute the fetch -- create a mutable copy of the result.
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"failed with error: %@", error);
    }

    // Set the array.
    [self setDataTripArray:mutableFetchResults];

    // Memory management.
    [fetchRequest release];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
}
```

Sometimes, I have leaks when I do the `[self setDataTripArray:mutableFetchResults];` and sometimes not. In this case, when I get the data for a trip, it leaks all the time when I use the navigation controller to come back to the root view controller (displaying a list of trips), and/or when I change tab.

Anyway, it just leaks and it's all the time coming from fetching data from CoreData, and give this array to my local array var.

Please let me know if you see how to fix this! It made the app crash after a while.
Thanks!

Comment: Is `setDataTripArray` an accessor of a retain property? If it is, do you release it in your `dealloc` method?

Comment: Yes it is. Here is the var declaration `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataTripArray;`. Oh I just found maybe where it comes from, I update my post that you can see.

Comment: Great! In the future remember that Instruments points to where the leaked object is created, not where it is leaked. BTW, it is ok to answer your own question instead of editing the question :)

Comment: Thanks @albertamg! I always use Instruments for leaks and memory allocation yes, but it was pointing on `[self setDataTripArray:mutableFetchResults];` and not on the `retain` later in my class. I still have some other leaks tho, but I'll find a way I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I found that I do a `retain` on my object `dataTripArray` object when creating another UIViewController that I use to create graphs for my scroll view.

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page
{
    if (page < 0)
        return;
    if (page >= kNumberOfPages)
        return;

    // Replace the placeholder if necessary.
    GraphController *controller = [self.graphControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
    {
        controller = [[GraphController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page data:[self.dataTripArray retain]];
        [self.graphControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

    // Add the controller's view to the scroll view.
    if (controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = _scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}
```

I just removed the `retain` and the leak is no longer coming up. Fixed!

Comment: +1 follow my advise and answer your own question instead of editing the original question